# SetImageDrawable

Tags: android, imageview

Can someone please help with this. I am generating a random number and based on this random number I want to pick a png file from my res/drawable-mdpi folder to display. This is the code I'm using:

```
    public void DisplayRandomPicture(int randomNumber) 
    {   
    String drawableName = "c"+ randomNumber;

    ImageView image= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  
    image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName, "res/drawable-mdpi", getPackageName())));

    }
```

All the files in the res/drawable-mdpi folder start with "c". There is something wrong with the image.setImageDrawable syntax. When I run my app it crashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void DisplayRandomPicture(int randomNumber) 
    {   
    String drawableName = "c"+ randomNumber;

    ImageView iw= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  
    resID = getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName, "drawable",  getPackageName());
    iw.setImageResource(resID);

    }
```

Try above and make sure the image exists with the exact name.

Comment: cant edit cause its too few characters, but `iw.set...` should be `image.set...`

Comment: Yes, this is what I figured out after plodding through some code. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. I was just dwelling on the same code in my project and thought it is the perfect moment to share the answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by using:

```
    int id = getBaseContext().getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName, "drawable", getPackageName());

    image.setImageResource(id);
```

Comment: I posted my answer before I saw yours. They are pretty much the same. I've changed it now and accepted yours. Happy? :-)